# How to call the SQL LIKE function in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Receiving NULL as value when I called this SQL statement (the record exists in the MySQL DB). How can use the LIKE function in Yii2? Thanks.

```
$command = $connection->createCommand("SELECT user_id
                         FROM User
                            WHERE name LIKE '%:_username%'");

$command->bindParam(':_username',$this->username);
$this->id_user = $command->queryScalar();
$command->execute();
```

Comment: Have you looked into using the [Query Builder](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-query-builder.html) instead of creating the command yourself? It might be more flexible for this type of call. It also has the benefit of handling [where cases](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-db-query.html#where()-detail) in different ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  Yii2 you can use also a activeQuery Notation this way

```
  $query = new Query;
  $query->select('userid')
      ->from('user')
      ->where(['like', 'user', $this->username );

  $command = $query->createCommand();

  $this->id_user = $command->queryScalar();
```

Comment: It works modifying the following line:   ->where(['like', 'user','%'.$this->username.'%', false]);

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap `"%value%"` in bindValue

```
 $command = $connection->createCommand("SELECT user_id
                             FROM User
                                WHERE name LIKE ':_username'");

    $command->bindParam(':_username',"%".$this->username."%");
    $this->id_user = $command->queryScalar();
    $command->execute();
```

Correct Way to bind value with %% is below

```
 $command->bindParam(':_username',"%".$this->username."%");
```

**just like as PDO we use**

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue here is with the `binding`.

Try, using this instead.

```
$command->bindParam('_username',$this->username);
```

Also not so sure what's the acceptable syntax for the variables, so if it's still not working try removing the `_` and use `username` on binding... and `:username` on the query.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but try to get the first % before the single quote and the last % after the last single quote.

```
$command = $connection->createCommand(
       "SELECT user_id
        FROM User
        WHERE name LIKE %':_username'%"
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Binding needs to be done on the entire data not just part of it.

```
$command = $connection->createCommand("SELECT user_id
                     FROM User
                        WHERE name LIKE :username");

$user = '%' . $this->username . '%';

$command->bindParam(':username',$user);
$this->id_user = $command->queryScalar();
$command->execute();
```

Comment: I have the following error after that statement: PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException Cannot pass parameter 2 by reference

Comment: You might need to turn it into a string first:
eg. 
$user = '%' . $this->username . '%';

$command->bindParam(':username',$user);

Answer (score 0):

I'm using bindValue. You can use like this..
I have a query in my model, and calls the functions on my Controller.

Inside Model:

```
$query = "SELECT u.id as idUser
FROM vagas_x_candidato vxc
INNER JOIN usuario u ON(u.id = vxc.id_candidato)
WHERE u.nome LIKE :nameUser";

$connection = \Yii::$app->db;
$model = $connection->createCommand($query);
$model->bindValue(":nameUser", '%' . $filter->nameU . '%');
return $model->queryAll();
```

Inside Controller:

```
$vxc = new VagasXCandidatoSearch();
$vxc = $vxc->candidatosPesquisaAvancada(); //calls my method on model.
```